# Issue with Leafet instelled locally

Tags: leaflet

I installed leafet by using npm package manager, installed once in laravel project and another time with vue project, in the both projects leaflet was not showing basemap layer correctly. but when I use leaflet CDN, it work perfectly.
How I can use leaflet instelled locally?

THis image below for map layer by installed leaflet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMuLN.jpg)

This image below for map layer by CDN leaflet. work perfectly inside it's box border with zoom and  pan
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOdQR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try to download files directly from CDN and import them into your project.